# Restoring relationship with friends

Tags: phrase-usage

Would you use the phrase "restoring relationship" meaning getting back in touch with friend you had a fight or is it wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It is a valid phrase for the meaning you request.

It also can mean getting back in touch with a friend with whom you have had no recent contact.  It does not necessarily imply the existence of an earlier fight.

Comment: Is there less formal way to say it?

Comment: "Make up" is a simple way to say work through your differences and become friends (or lovers) again.  (Lovers "break up" and go their separate ways, and sometimes "make up" and get back together again.)  There are other ways to say this: "fix things between us", "straighten things out between us", "bury the hatchet", "clear the air", and "pick a bone with someone", among others.  These have varying shades of meaning and formality.